# setTimeout and passing variables to anonymous function together

Tags: javascript, html

i'm writing a code and i've stuck with setTimeout function. I would like to get animation effect. Display elements of array with delay. Code is done.

```
for (var i=0;i <= array.length-1;i++) {
                        (function(el) {
                            setTimeout(function(){
                             document.getElementById('Result').innerHTML += Math.floor(el);
                             console.log(Math.floor(el));
                            }, 3000*(i+1));
                        })(array[i]);
```

I had problem with delay when i use `for (var i=array.length-1; i>=0;i--)` Why? (The idea of this code is display items array form the last to the first)

```
for (var i=0;i <= array.length-1;i++) {
                        (function(el) {
                            setTimeout(function(){
```

Give now the same resultat as: `for (var i=array.length-1; i>=0;i--) {
                        console.log(array[i]+'!')`

Comment: Any particular reason why you aren't using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)? It makes this sort of thing is *really* trivial.

Comment: In your `setTimeout` code snippet you didn't put in a delay time: `}(array,i), 3000);`

Comment: You are calling the function immediately and pass the return value `undefined` to `setTimeout`.

Comment: jQuery has nothing to do with this; it's just not written correctly. you do need an anon in the loop to capture i and array, but that anon needs to be invoked immediately. instead, you are invoking the setTimeout callback immediately.

Comment: *"YOU ANSVERS DONT WORK! Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ( "* I think syntax errors are the easiest thing to fix. Read these articles to [learn](http://juliepagano.com/blog/2014/05/18/javascript-debugging-for-beginners) [how to](http://www.creativebloq.com/javascript/javascript-debugging-beginners-3122820) [**debug** JavaScript](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging), so you can help yourself.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem here is about **closures**. A closure is a type of anonymous function used to remember the arguments for using them later in asynchronous code (e.g. in functions called by `setTimeout`).

If you write something like:

```
setTimeout(function(foo){...}(value), 3000)
```

the function gets called before calling `setTimeout`. You have to use a closure to do this:

```
(function(foo){ 
    setTimeout(function() { 
        ... do something with foo ... 
    }, 3000);
})(value_of_foo);
```

This code will remember the value of `foo` creating a `setTimeout` with a function that uses it.

Another problem is that you have to increase the `setTimeout` time to create a delay, otherwise the `for` will create a bunch of `setTimeout(..., 3000)` that will be executed all at once. So what you will need to do to your code is something like the following:

```
for (var i = 0; i <= array.length; i++) {
    (function(el) {
        setTimeout(function(){
            document.getElementById('Result').innerHTML += Math.floor(el)
        }, 3000 * i);
    })(array[i]); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Timeouts don't execute until after your main function has finished, this means that by the time your timeout function executes per loop, your i variable will be at its final value (in this case = 0).  Your function declaration is also incorrect as the timeout function does not pass in those parameters for you.  To do this, you need to wrap your timeout inside of another function call that takes in the parameters for the current loop, try something like this instead...

```
for (var i=array.length-1; i>=0;i--) {
  function(array, i) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      document.getElementById('Result').innerHTML += Math.floor(array[i]);
    }, (i+1) * 3000);
  }(array, i);
}
```

Comment: I think you are missing something here. The code is syntactically invalid.

Comment: for animation, shouldn't that 0 be i or maybe (i*10) ?

Comment: I've put (i+1) * 3000 as the delay, but it can be changed to however much delay you want

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli sorry, fixed

Answer (score 0):

First of all you are immediately calling the function and its result is assigned as the callback of the timeout. (*this is wrong as the first argument must be a function*)

Then, you have some syntax errors with missing closing `}` and `)`..

Try

```
for (var i=array.length-1; i>=0;i--) {
    function(array,i){ 
        setTimeout(function(){
            document.getElementById('Result').innerHTML += Math.floor(array[i]);
        }, 3000*i);
    }(array,i);
}
```

I used `3000*i` so that each timeout is 3 seconds after the other

Comment: it would seem to be going backwards for animation, so you should likely count up... the code shown also doesn't run in chrome due to a syntax error :(

Comment: @dandavis, yes.. i have already updated..